# Cannot connect to Redis from Spring Boot inside docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, redis, jedis

I have a problem with connection from spring boot application to redis inside docker containers. I tried to change protected-mode to no and change binding in redis but it isn`t working for me. I also tried to change redis host to 'redis' from 'localhost' but its not working too. I am trying to dockerize my application for a long time thats why I am asking for help. I am using Jedis btw.

There are some problems from logs for the last time:
`Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

You can find my code here:
https://github.com/CommoMegaSator/Versatile-Development

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgresql
    volumes:
      - /opt/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "3001:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=versatile
      - POSTGRES_SCHEMA=main
    restart: on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    expose:
      - 3001
    networks:
      - versatile

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    command: [ "redis-server", "--protected-mode", "no", "--bind", "0.0.0.0" ]
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB, FLUSHALL
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "3002:6379"
    networks:
      - versatile

  versatile:
    image: versatile
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: versatile
    ports:
      - "3000:8081"
    restart: on-failure
    links:
      - redis
      - postgresql
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgresql
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/versatile
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_SCHEMA=main
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
    expose:
      - 8081
    networks:
      - versatile

networks:
  versatile:
    driver: bridge
```

And my application.properties:

```
#Spring DATASOURCE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/versatile
spring.datasource.hikari.schema=main
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = postgres
flyway.createSchemas=true
spring.flyway.schemas=main

#Spring JPA properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true
spring.jpa.show-sql = false

#Redis properties
spring.session.store-type = redis
spring.session.redis.flush-mode = on_save
spring.session.redis.namespace = spring:session
spring.cache.type = redis
spring.redis.host = localhost
spring.redis.password =
spring.redis.port = 6379
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducable example to your question and don't expect people here to go through your entire code for troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

In your applicatiopn properties you have defined the host for both the database and redis as *localhost* :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/versatile
spring.redis.host = localhost
```

This may be correct if you are running everything on your local development machine, but in the docker-compose scenario you need to set the hostnames to be the names assigned to the docker containers - i.e. the values set as the `container_name` in the compose file. That is `postgresql` and `redis` respectively.

Comment: I tried to change redis host to redis from localhost but result is same.

Comment: you will need to troubleshoot then. Things to look at ... is redis up and running on the port you think it is (3002 on the container itself), is the networking current (config looks ok) - CLI onto the test container and check you can see/connect to the redis container. Looks the the logs for any clue as to the problem, check redis logs that is started ok, see if you can enable more logging to help troubleshoot.